# I already have 1 code commit account set up, how do I set up a second code commit account? (I'm getting a clone error on the second account)

Tags: git, macos, aws-codecommit

When I try and clone a new code commit repo on my MAC I get a 403 error. I'm completely lost as to what I need to do to get 2 different accounts to work.

When I run git config -l --show-orgin I have these settings.

```
$ git config -l --show-origin
file:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/git-core/gitconfig   credential.helper=osxkeychain
file:/Users/username/.gitconfig       user.email=firstnamelastname@company.com
```

my .aws/credentials file contains the following from the first account

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=xxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

my credential-helper.sh. file contains from the first code commit account

```
echo username="[xxxxxxxx]"
echo password="[xxxxxxxxxxxxx]"
```

I'm new to code commit and am not sure what I need to edit in order to clone the second repo.

When I do try and clone into it, I get the below error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.xxxxxxxxx/v1/repos/xxxxxxxx/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

What am I missing here? We haven't set up ssh on the second account yet and are just using a username and password for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your `credential-helper.sh` to be used by your second repo (as described in [this article](https://alanedwardes.com/blog/posts/git-username-password-environment-variables/)), you would need to:

- initialize an empty repo locally
- add a local setting instructing to use that credential
- add a remote to the remote repo
- fetch

That is:

```
git init .
git config credential.helper "/bin/bash /full/path/to/credential-helper.sh"
git remote add origin https://git-codecommit.xxxxxxxxx/v1/repos/xxxxxxxx/
git fetch
git switch master
```

Comment: Is it possible to use the shell file for both repos? (2 different accounts?) I don't want to switch the file from the first repo to the second repo, but rather use it for both.

Comment: @cauthon it is best to keep those files separate, to avoid any account mix-up.